# Introduce delay between master slave setup in MariaDB

Tags: replication, mariadb

We're using a master-slave solution using MariaDB 5.5.44. Is there a way to manually introduce an artificial delay between the master and slave? I'm thinking of something like 1 minute or so. Is there a `mysqld` option that does this?

I see that MySQL 5.6 has the `MASTER_DELAY` parameter for the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command, but I suppose it doesn't exist in 5.5 (or MariaDB 5.5). Is there another way to cause a delay?

Answer (score 2):

The `MASTER_DELAY` option is currently scheduled to be in MariaDB 10.2.  There is an [issue](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7145) for the feature.

Until that is added to MariaDB, your best option is [pt-slave-delay](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-slave-delay.html) from Percona.  I've used it before and it is pretty easy to get going but since it isn't part of the mysql server, it's not as reliable.